# how to change the style of div on click div

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have made a website which saves record and images in a database.
But when I click on `div` and see the record on any members I want to change div colour and when I see record.
I want to change style of div.
When I click any div then image load on this div. How can I do it?
It means `style1` work on div when click any div
My code is :

```js
<script>
function changelod(obj)
{
obj.setAttribute("class", "style1");
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.style1{background:transparent url('12/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;}
#content {clear:left;overflow:auto;width:780px;height:auto;padding:5px 5px;}
#left {float:left;width:242px;padding:5px 5px;border:1px solid #000;}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="left">
<div id="leftbox" class="style">
<a onclick="changelod(this);" href="members.php&code=<?php echo $myrowadfix["securtycode"]; ?>" target="_blank">
<div id="boxbody">
<img src="img/8.gif" height="100" width="100">
<p><?php echo $myrowadfix["histrym"]; ?>">
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Help in this code I try this code but div move top of page and image load
on this and scrollbar show on this div

Comment: function changelod(obj) { 
       obj.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "style1");
}no work

Answer (score 0):

In your changelod(obj) function, obj is the TAG , because you pass the this parameter.

If you want to change the class of his parent (  ), you just have to select the parent of this:

```
obj.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "style1");
```

For reference, u can read something here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
    function changelod(obj) { 
       obj.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "style1");
}
```